# For a better animation of the solution from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

I obtained a numerical solution from the following code with `NDSolve`

```
L = 20;
tmax = 27;
\[Sigma] = 2;
myfun = First[h /. NDSolve[{D[h[x, y, t], t] +
Div[h[x, y, t]^3*Grad[Laplacian[h[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
Div[h[x, y, t]^3*Grad[h[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
h[x, y, 0] == 1 +
1/(2*\[Pi]*\[Sigma]^2)*Exp[-((x - 10)^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2) + (y - 10)^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2))],
h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t], h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t]}, 
h, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 60, "MaxPoints" -> 60, 
"DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, StepMonitor :> Print[t]]]
```

(*It took about 7 sec to be solved on my old laplop.*)

Next, I am trying to make an animation and export a .gif file to present its evolution as follows: (*taking about 50 sec*)

```
mpl = Table[Plot3D[myfun[x, y, t], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotPoints -> 40, ImageSize -> 400, 
PlotLabel -> Style["t = " <> ToString[t], Bold, 18]], {t, 0, 27, 1}];
Export["test.gif", mpl, "DisplayDurations" -> 1, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

[image]

**Here are my questions:**

As you may see, during the evolution **(1)** the box(frame) of the animation is shrinking and expanding, though slightly, **(2)** the augment in the amplitude is shown through increasing the vertical coordinate. If one neglects the scaling in this coordinate and only observe the middle peak, he may do not feel its growth. This is a problem in make a presentation.

I don't know the reason for the fist observation, for the second one, while, I think MMA try to highlight the surface variation at *every* instant by scaling the vertical axis synchronously.

Can anyone please help me to suppress the oscillation of the 3Dbox and hold the coordinate of vertical axis as the final frame at $t_\text{max}=27$ (i.e. about z=6 here) because I want to show the surface evolution form a small fluctuation to the final big amplitude. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the physics you are capturing with your PDE?

Comment: Hi, @drN, I remember that it was just a simplified version of a film equation from your post and others' papers :)

Comment: nice! And you are trying to create a pendant drop due to gravity and surface tension? You should check out our work from the 2010 Wolfram tech conference. Search for Allan Struthers. He had similar code that creates pretty much the same kind of spatiotemporal pattern as you.

Comment: @drN. Hi, drN, yep, really appreciate your information! I am still new to MMA though have used it for one year. I am not used to the the Wolfram language logic. I think I can learn something from you and your post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To prevent shaking, try to add `ImagePadding` and for the other issue, you can fix the vertical plot range.

```
mpl = Table[
   Plot3D[myfun[x, y, t], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 6}}, PlotPoints -> 40, 
    ImageSize -> 400, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["t = " <> ToString[t], Bold, 18], 
    ImagePadding -> 30], {t, 0, 27, 1}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I only post this as a way (without distortion or dealing with multiple scales)to illustrate the initial Gaussian (flat relative to final range) with `MeshFunctions` and using `ColorFunction`. I have voted for Nasser's answer.

```
fun[t_] := Legended[Show[
   Plot3D[myfun[x, y, t], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
    MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {{0, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Thick, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z/6]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRange -> {0, 6},
    PlotPoints -> 40,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"t= ", t}], 20, White, Bold]], 
   Background -> Black], BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 6}}]]
```

The gif was exported from `fun/@Range[0,27,0.5]` at 8 frames per second (using `"DisplayDurations"`.

[image]

Comment: your method is quite good for a presentation. Thank! If it can accept two answers, I will definitely choose your as well.

Comment: @jsxs Nasser provides the direct answer. I would not change your accept. I voted for Nasser as well.  I just aimed to illustrate one way to show you start with a flat Gaussian. There are other ways and play is one of the best teachers (for me at least). :)